# Design a Chess game (using OOPS and Java Design Pattern)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, chess

Can someone help me build a chess game from the scratch using Java OOPS and Design patterns concepts.

A rough model is enough. 
Are there any links/blogs for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a very broad question.

Second, Object Oriented approaches are somewhat slow, which will decrease the engines play strength.

That said, here is roughly what you need:
- a piece class, or an enum, or something similar

- a chessboard class, where you can place and move pieces
- a move generator, this is a function that lists all legal moves of a chessboard
- an evaluation function that "rates" chesspositions, wheter black or white has an advantage
- a minimax function, (see google "minimax algorithm"), that returns the best move in a position
- some kind of gui for the whole thing

For more info, see the chessprogramming wiki.

Answer (score -4):

I would have a class for the games map, a class for a figure (and childclasses for tower, king aso.). Also probably a class for the player.